# How to unit test an errorexception with mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

Suppose I have this function:

```
 try
 {
    if (s1 <0 || s2<0 ||s3 <0){
            throw new Error('InvalidTriangleExeption ');
    }
    let  s = (s1 + s2 + s3)/2;
    var area =  Math.sqrt(s*((s-s1)*(s-s2)*(s-s3)));
    return area;
    }
 catch{
        throw new Error('InvalidTriangleExeption ');
 }}
```

I am trying to write a mocha unit test:

```
expect( question3(-1,4,5)).to.throw('InvalidTriangleExeption')
```

But my test just crashes with an error:

```
 Error: InvalidTriangleExeption 
      at go (src/questions/question3.js:13:15)
      at Context.<anonymous> (tests/question3.spec.js:14:13)
```

How can I write an assertion for a mocha test which confirms the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind args to solve this issue

```
expect(question3.bind(this, -1, 5, 4)).to.throw(); // PASS
expect(question3.bind(this, -1, 5, 4)).to.throw('InvalidTriangleExeption'); // PASS
expect(question3.bind(this, -1, 5, 4)).to.throw('ABCExeption'); // FAIL

expect(question3.bind(this, -1, 5, 4)).to.not.throw('InvalidTriangleExeption'); // FAIL
expect(question3.bind(this, -1, 5, 4)).to.not.throw('ABCExeption'); // PASS
expect(question3.bind(this, -1, 5, 4)).to.not.throw(); // FAIL
```